# CMake and running PC-Lint at file-level in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, pc-lint

Is there way to run PC-Lint either for a specific file or for the whole project in CMake-generated Visual Studio projects?

Currently I'm able to run PC-Lint per-project by creating custom targets using [Kitware's script](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/PC-Lint), but in my environment linting the whole project may take up to 10 minutes. So, I would also like to have a possibility to lint a specific source file only (and to choose that file from Visual Studio).

I was thinking, if PC lint could be used as custom "compiler" and to create for my target another project_LINT target that uses the lint "compiler". Then I could maybe select individual files to be "compiled". Or is this idea doomed? :)

Comment: Using their example: 

if(COMMAND add_pc_lint)
 add_pc_lint(main ${MAIN_SOURCES})
endif(COMMAND add_pc_lint) 

Why not create a LINT_SOURCES variable in addition to all of your project sources and use that instead of MAIN_SOURCES?

Comment: @RyanMaloney: Maybe my question was a bit unclear. I would like to choose from Visual Studio a specific file that I'm working on (e.g. utils.cpp) that is linted. In addition I would like to have an option to lint the whole project. Thus, your solution isn't working. I'll update the question. Thanks for suggestion, anyway!